# Postgresql how to select columns where it matches conditions?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table like this:

```
inventory_id | customer_id |         max         
--------------+-------------+---------------------
         4497 |           1 | 2005-07-28 00:00:00
         1449 |           1 | 2005-08-22 00:00:00
         1440 |           1 | 2005-08-02 00:00:00
         3232 |           1 | 2005-08-02 00:00:00
         3418 |           2 | 2005-08-02 00:00:00
          654 |           2 | 2005-08-02 00:00:00
         3164 |           2 | 2005-08-21 00:00:00
         2053 |           2 | 2005-07-27 00:00:00
```

I want to select rows where most recent date with corresponding columns, This is what I want to achieve:

```
inventory_id | customer_id |         max         
--------------+-------------+---------------------
         1449 |           1 | 2005-08-22 00:00:00
         3164 |           2 | 2005-08-21 00:00:00
```

I tried to use aggregate but I need inventory_id and customer_id appear at the same time.
Is there any method that could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (customer_id) t.*
from t
order by customer_id, max desc;
```

`distinct on` is a Postgres extension that returns on row per whatever is in the parentheses.  This row is based on the `order by` -- the first one that appears in the sorted set.

Comment: I want to find inventroy_id and customer_id with most recent date.

Comment: @Rrobinvip . . . That is what the query in this answer does, assuming `max` is the name of the column with the date you are referring to.

Comment: Thanks.. I've just figured out the logic behind this

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT inventory_id, customer_id, max FROM 
    (SELECT inventory_id, customer_id, max, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY max DESC) AS ROWNO 
    FROM inventory_table) AS A
    WHERE ROWNO=1
```